# AVPlayerViewController not showing entire duration label

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

The problem I am facing is that when I try to play a remote video with a long duration (hours), AVPlayerViewController duration labels (both elapsed and remaining) will not show the entire duration. A screenshot below shows the problem:

[image: duration labels trimmed]

Code:

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Play", style: .default) { (action) in
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: {
                    self.player?.play()
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @AndreiKonstantinov I did what you said. Same problem however I updated my code in the question which might help you get a better idea of the issue.

Comment: @AndreiKonstantinov Still no help?

Comment: Can I ask you to setup a short code example with reproducible behaviour? On github, for example, and post a link here?

Comment: @AndreiKonstantinov I used a different player which solved my issue. Thank you.